# AWS Cloudformation - Elasticsearch Access Control Policies Service Error InvalidTypeException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to limit access to my elasticsearch clusters on aws by defining `Access Policies` that would limit access to iam users, a specific lambda function and the appsync api.

I have defined the following `access policies` in the elasticsearch resource on cloudformation, but this is failing with an error: `Service: AWSElasticsearch; Status Code: 409; Error Code: InvalidTypeException;`

How do I fix my policy so that it works?

```
"Type": "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain",
        "Properties": {
            "AccessPolicies": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": [
                                {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "",
                                        [
                                            "arn:aws:lambda:",
                                            {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                            ":",
                                            {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},
                                            ":function:",
                                            {"Ref": "DdEsLambdaFunctionName"},
                                            "-",
                                            {"Ref": "env"}
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "",
                                        [
                                            {"Ref": "GraphQLAPI"},
                                            "/*"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Action": [
                            "es:ESHttp*"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": [
                            {
                                "AWS": {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "",
                                        [
                                            "arn:aws:iam::",
                                            {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},
                                            ":user/*"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Action": "*"
                    }
                ]
            },...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the core issue, but your first `Principal` is incorrect.

You specified `Service` but you provide lambda ARN. The ARN is of type `AWS` principal, not `Service`. Possibly `GraphQLAPI` is also an ARN, which again is not a `Service` principal, but `AWS` Principal.

Comment: Nope, same error. I had initially tried with 'AWS' as principal

Comment: It turns out elasticsearch access policies only accept principals of type iam or ipv4 address. Lambda and appsync are not accepted types